# Whole curve twisting when moving it's extremity

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

Is there a way to improve on this kind of curve behavior? I'm making a belt, and it's driving me crazy how the whole curve go nuts when you tweak the starting point position. You would think changing the twist method under the curve parameter would work, as well as the twist smoothing, but none of the options feels like a good one in my case.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the algorythms to predict how you wish the object to be twisted, you can specify manually for each vertex of the curve:

[image]

Comment: Yes I assumed this was due to this kind of limitation, and I know about twisting individual points. I'm wondering if I could fix it through some rigging magic. I just want to be able to place belts on the bags I'm making really fast, this needs to be easily to tweak, so curves are a great choice for me in that regards.